# fix invalid CSV row with "Illegal quoting" error in Ruby code

Tags: ruby, csv

For some reason, the csv file has some lines in it with "Illegal quoting" error, e.g.:

1336481227,178.108.171.183,3.2.0,9700132ccc02e12a,c083b5d2-ec92-486f-a5b3-512dba1ce4ae,invoke_action,"{""timestamp"":""2012-05-08 13:47:26""}"

1336481227,178.108.171.183,3.2.0,9700132ccc02e12a,c083b5d2-ec92-486f-a5b3-512dba1ce4ae,invoke_action,{""timestamp"":""2012-05-08 13:47:27""}

The first row is correct. But the last field {""timestamp"":""2012-05-08 13:47:27""} in the second row is missing the double quotes outside the curly brackets, so when I tried to

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file_path) do |row|
    puts "======================="
    puts row
    puts "======================="
end
```

I got error

```
=======================
1336481227
178.108.171.183
3.2.0
9700132ccc02e12a
c083b5d2-ec92-486f-a5b3-512dba1ce4ae
invoke_action
{"timestamp":"2012-05-08 13:47:26","a":"b"}
=======================
#<CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 2.>
```

Is there anyway I can fix this row with such problem or just skip it when error happens?

Edited:
If I try

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file_path, :quote_char => "\'") do |row|
    puts "======================="
    puts row
    puts "======================="
end
```

The first row's JSON format value is broken though:

```
=======================
1336481227
178.108.171.183
3.2.0
9700132ccc02e12a
c083b5d2-ec92-486f-a5b3-512dba1ce4ae
invoke_action
"{""timestamp"":""2012-05-08 13:47:26""
""a"":""b""}"
=======================
=======================
1336481227
178.108.171.183
3.2.0
9700132ccc02e12a
c083b5d2-ec92-486f-a5b3-512dba1ce4ae
invoke_action
{""timestamp"":""2012-05-08 13:47:27""}
=======================
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file_path, :quote_char => "\'")
```

Comment: or you can ```gsub '""', '"'``` in order to get normal csv and JSON

Comment: This will break those rows that doesn't have the "Illegal quoting" error. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is use double gsub

```
require 'csv'
line = "1336481227,178.108.171.183,3.2.0,9700132ccc02e12a,c083b5d2-ec92-486f-a5b3-512dba1ce4ae,invoke_action,\"{\"\"timestamp\"\":\"\"2012-05-08 13:47:26\"\",\"\"a\"\":\"\"b\"\"}\""
line.gsub!('""', '%tmp%')
csv = CSV.new(line).each.map do |line|
  line.map do |value|
    value.gsub!('%tmp%', '""')
    value
  end
end

puts csv.inspect
# => [["1336481227", "178.108.171.183", "3.2.0", "9700132ccc02e12a", "c083b5d2-ec92-486f-a5b3-512dba1ce4ae", "invoke_action", "{\"\"timestamp\"\":\"\"2012-05-08 13:47:26\"\",\"\"a\"\":\"\"b\"\"}"]]
```